# A graph that contains three spanning trees is non-planar

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that a graph of order $6$ or  more that contains three spanning trees such that every edge of a graph belongs to exactly one of these trees is non-planar

I proceeded by showing that the size of this graph doesn't satisfy the upper bound for planar graphs , that's, $m=3n-6$ since the graph has three spanning trees such that each edge of the graph belongs to one of them then the size is $m=3n-3$

Is this a correct reasoning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that sounds like it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/804481)

Comment: @mlc: What more do you want? The OP presented an argument, wanted to know whether it works, and the correct answer to that question is, "yes, that works".